# Compression support for PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed phpmyadmin on ubuntu with `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin`.

Now I like to activate compression support for databases. How can I achive that?

Is there an easier solution than remove the package and install phppmyadmin from source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I get in @kos'es way, but I just have to happen a phpMyAdmin installation handy ;) Ubuntu 14.04 LTS comes with phpMyAdmin 4.0.10. That version offers you two choices on the "export" tab: "Quick - display only the minimal options" and "Custom - display all possible options".

If you choose "Custom", you should get a bunch of additional options. Among those, in the "Output" section, you can choose which compression you'd like to use.